# Probar funciones que cree en Haskell

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

verán instale un emulador de ubuntu hace 1 año y ahora que estoy cursando en la facultad hacemos funciones en haskell y verán, me olvide como probar las funciones que creo en el archivo.hs y probarlas en la terminal de haskell.

Espero hacerme entender, **tengo instalado ghci pero no recuerdo el procedimiento para poder usar esas funciones que cree**, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

1. Navega hasta donde lo guardaste y ejecuta ghci desde ahí.
2. Una vez dentro de GHCi, escribe `:l baby`. Ahora que tu código está cargado, podrás jugar con las funciones que has definido.
3. Las funciones en GHCi son llamadas mediante su nombre seguido de sus parámetros tal que así: `doubleMe 9`

Si quieres + info, la tienes aquí: [Tutorial de Haskell](http://aprendehaskell.es/content/Empezando.html)

Ya nos cuentas que tal.. y bienvenido a SOe!

Comment: si muchas gracias era una pavada, ahi pude probar, gracias sergio :)

Comment: Me alegro ! No hay de qué